# How to edit contents grabbed using file_get_contents

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I grabbed some urls and titles by using file_get_contents. Now I want to edit them and display in my page. But I don't think its possible.

```
$html = file_get_html($gg_url);
// find all div tags with id=s
$ttt = $html->find('div.s');
```

The result is:

```
www.example.com and bla bla bla under that DIV
```

But that url is tagged like this `<cite>www.exaple.com</cite>`.

All I need is that url inside the result but whole thing (url + other text) is in one variable. Is there a way to get that url?

Answer (score 3):

```
$html = file_get_html($gg_url);
$ttt = $html->find('cite')->innertext;
echo $ttt;
```